# $textrun->addText content being processed before $footer->addText content

Tags: php, phpword

I want to have a footer that contains 3 lines of text, with a vertical space (like a blank line) between lines 2 and 3.
Because line 3 contains bold and normal text, I have to implement it as a textrun. 
But there should be a line break between lines 1 and 2, so I use addText for both of these.

Unfortunately, the order in which the footer content is displayed is as follows:

- textrun

  footerText1
  footerText2

The textrun gets processed first and appears above the other lines!

How do I get the order right?

My footer code is:

```
// create footer
$footer = $section->addFooter();

// textrun declaration removed from here

// create footer content
$footerText1 = "Blah blah blah.";

$footerText2 = "Ipsum loret Ipsum loret Ipsum loret.";


// define font styles  
$smallFontStyleName = 'smallText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($smallFontStyleName, array(
    'name' => 'Helvetica',
    'size' => 8,
));

$boldSmallFontStyleName = 'BoldSmallText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($boldSmallFontStyleName, array(
    'bold' => true,
    'name' => 'Helvetica',
    'size' => 8,
));


// define paragraph spacing styles
$phpWord->addParagraphStyle('line1FooterStyle', array( 'spaceAfter'=>20));

$phpWord->addParagraphStyle('line2FooterStyle', array( 'spaceAfter'=>380));


// add content
$footer->addText($footerText1, 
    array('name' => 'Helvetica', 'size' => 8),
    array('space' => array('after' => 20))
);

$footer->addText($footerText2, 
    array('name' => 'Helvetica', 'size' => 8), 
    array('space' => array('after' => 380))
);
```

// textrun relocated to here

```
$textrun = $footer->addTextRun();

$textrun->addText('T', $boldSmallFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' ++353 1 555 0001 ', $smallFontStyleName); 
$textrun->addText('E', $boldSmallFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' abc.def@ghk.ie ', $smallFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText('W', $boldSmallFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' abcd.ie/wxz', $smallFontStyleName);
```

Comment: One option is probably to drop using `addFooter()` and implement the entire footer as textrun.

Comment: But I need line breaks after lines 1 and 2. I'll try multiple textruns and see how that goes.

Comment: OK, I saw the problem and fixed it. I had declared the textrun before the $footer->addText lines. Which means the textrun code was inserted first, incorrectly. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I saw the problem and fixed it. I had declared the textrun before the $footer->addText lines. Which means the textrun code was inserted first, incorrectly. D'oh!